Confused by a derivation using logs
This link discusses the Project Euler problem 34; as part of the discussion, the following bound is found: $$10^{d-1}\le d\cdot9!<10^d \Rightarrow d\le7.33<d+1$$
The derivation begins by taking $\log_{10}$ of both sides and using well-known log properties, which I can understand perfectly well, and arrives at $$d-\log_{10}(d)\le\log_{10}(9!)+1<d-\log_{10}(d)+1,$$ with $\log_{10}(9!)+1\approx6.56$.
It then replaces the $d$s inside the $\log$s with $6$, i.e. $$d-\log_{10}(6)\le6.56<d-\log_{10}(6)+1 \Rightarrow d\le7.33<d+1,$$ but I am struggling to see why substituting $d$ with $6$ is a valid step.
Can anyone offer an explanation?

Did my answer help you?

He's just trying $d=6$. The result is that even with every digit being $9$ the sum of their factorials can't be a $6$ digit number. With a larger $d$ the difference would even larger. Thus, we can see that $d$ has to be smaller than $6$.
EDIT:
One method you could do here is just try $d=1$, $d=2$, etc. Then you'll notice that $d=6$ is the first one that's not possible. The discussion behind that link just jumps ahead and doesn't show that (mild) tedium. Or maybe he just made a lucky guess.
